# Вывод определенных словарей из списка

Tags: postgresql

В таблице имеется колонка товара `name_column JSONB[]`.

```
name_column = ARRAY[{"id": 1, "valid": true},
                    {"id": 2, "valid": false},
                    {"id": 3, "valid": false},
                    {"id": 4, "valid": true}]
```

Меня волнует как можно вывести именно те словари, в которых `valid = true`.
Проблема в том, что при таком запросе
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name_column -> 0 -> 'valid' = true;` выдает ошибку `ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb[] -> integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT unnest(name_column) as value
    FROM schema.table) ff
WHERE (ff.value->>'valid')::bool is true;

Out:
"{""id"": 1, ""valid"": true}"
"{""id"": 4, ""valid"": true}"
```

Функция `unnest` распаковывает массив в колонку, а дальше уже выбираете по условию.

Comment: Этого не было в вопросе, но всё же... Как можно узнать количество подходящих элементов в списке. Дело в том что всего в списке 10 элементов, из них 1-9 подходят по условию. Мне нужно узнать сколько подходят по условию. Изменить ваш запрос в начале как `SELECT count(*) ...` не будет верным решением, т.к всего в таблице 100 строк.

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll если в исходной таблице есть поле id или какой то другой уникальный идентификатор строки, то его можно запросить в подзапросе вместе с `unnest`, а потом делать `count` с группировкой по нему.

Comment: Если его нет, то первое что приходит в голову - это написание свой функции которая для каждой строки добавляла бы порядковый номер, хотя возможно есть решение проще - посмотрите документацию.